# How to access page by address in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In the interactive report I developed with Apex, the table on the home page shows the information of a list of projects, including project name, owner etc. And the project name field of each project is a click which redirect to another page that shows more detailed project's information. In short, there is a link on the home page which directs to the page A. Sometimes, I need to copy and paste the address of this page A and send it to my colleagues so that they can go to that page directly by copying the address to their browser. However, when I　tried to use the address to view the page, I got redirect to the home page instead of page A. Why this is the case? How can I achieve the redirection I want in APEX?

P.S. My APEX application do have access control where only authorised people can create and edit items in the report, but everyone can view the item and the page A is the viewing page. I am not sure if this access control have anything to do with the issue.

Comment: probably because the url contains an invalid session id

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from APEX forum, so I am gonna write the answer here so that it might be of some help.

The url has a session id, which belongs to the app. By default, if you copy and paste this address to another browser, a new session will be created and the old id will not be valid anymore and the url will redirect you to the login page or the home page. If you want to make this url valid all the time, you need change the deep link attribute to be enabled under the authentication. Please refer to [Deep Linking](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldr_attr.htm#CHDHIFEJ) for more details.